# SonarQube analysis on JSX file

Tags: reactjs, sonarqube, sonarjs

I need to run SonarQube analysis for .jsx file . Is there any way so that we can run sonar-runner to analyse JSX file for performance issue?

Comment: I have written a tutorial on that subject : http://sylvainleroy.com/2017/05/14/SonarQube-and-ReactJS/ You may want to install another plugin to better cover JSX Files using ESLint.

Comment: @SylvainLeroy Can you look at my problem and give a suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59419678/sonarqube-with-reactjs-false-positive-on-duplicates-and-coverage-on-new-code Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can try to add:

```
sonar.javascript.file.suffixes=.js,.jsx
```

in your sonar-project.properties file. The default value is .js, so only those files will be parsed by Sonar.

Comment: Hey, this works only for coverage metrics? What if I want to add sonar.testExectuionReportPath with jsx files intend to see unit tes count for project?

Answer (score 3):

JSX is supported by the [SonarQube JavaScript plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJS) since version 2.12.

See [SONARJS-521](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-521) for more information.

Comment: OK THANKS ...I HAVE INSTALLED UPDATED VERSION OF JAVA SCRIPT 2.12 BUT STILL .JSX ISSUE IS NOT COMING. IT ONLY ANALYSIS BUNDLE.JS FILE WHICH IS PRODUCE FROM .JSX FILE .