# SonarQube with ReactJS - false positive on duplicates and coverage on new code

Tags: reactjs, sonarqube

I'm trying to analyze ongoing ReactJS project using SonarQube (first time with that tool) version 6.7.5 but after second code scan I'm getting Quality Gate failed due to 0% Coverage on New Code and 5% Duplicated Lines on New Code.

First problem - I have no clue why I'm getting it at all (no coverage on new code) when I see new code got picked up by SonarQube. It looks like most of functional components are not covered by tests.

Second problem - duplicates. Most of them are false positive like import statements or declarations (ex. react-table and columns declaration). Is there any way to mark them as non-duplicate? Or is there any workaround to get those kind of code blocks as valid (not dups)?

Answer (score 1):

**To touch on your first question:** 
Do you have the prerequisites set up?
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/javascript/

And have you configured reportPaths and a reporter?
I think that SonarQube needs this to run concurrently with your testing framework's coverage tool to analyse the overall project coverage data.
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/

**Your second issue** might be sorted by the first solution.
(I'm actually here because of my own problem: SonarQube isn't analysing a React component / JSX correctly and is seeing it as a code duplication. It's not my project, so I might just have to ask higher up to upgrade SonarQube... hopefully that solves it for me.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. For the first question - I have set first part and it looks like I don't have set coverage part correctly. 

For the second question - let me know if you found any solution as it looks like you are facing the same problem.